# Protractor - variable assigned to element.all.locator.count is returning NaN why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Protractor, and trying to grab all elements within a drop down list.

I have the following and this part appears to be working:

```
var counter = element.all(By.className('class')).count();
console.log(counter);
```

I expected the value to be 43 instead I received this from the console log:

```
{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

So not giving up, I then decided to see if I can output this value to a search bar inside the web application I'm testing on. To see what value it displays:

```
element(by.className('search_bar')).sendKeys(counter);
```

When I run it again:
I see the value in the search bar become populated with 43. This is what I am expecting to be what counter is equal to.

I then proceed to use the variable 'counter' in other places, and I keep getting values back as:

```
NaN
```

How do I get it to pass the actual number value of 43 but as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protractor` is a wrapper around `WebdriverJS` which is completely asynchronous and is based on a concept of promises. Basically, when you write `protractor` tests, think about everything as a promise. See [Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow).

`count()` **returns a promise**. In order to see or use an actual count value, **resolve it**:

```
var counter = element.all(By.className('class')).count();
counter.then(function (value) {
    element(by.className('search_bar')).sendKeys(value);
});
```

Note that if you pass a promise to `expect()` it would make an expectation only when the promise is resolved. This is because it is enhanced to do so in [`jasminewd`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd) which protractor depends on. In other words, you can write:

```
expect(counter).toEqual(10);
```

and let `expect()` worry about the promise.